# Automating an entry for terminal

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I have a problem which do not really know how to ask. I will try to explain as best as possible.

I have to automate an installation process using a bash script. In the middle of the process I make a call to a Python script called configure.py. This script expects input terminal.

Is there any way to call the script by passing terminal arguments waiting for?

```
Determining the layout of your Qt installation...
This is the GPL version of PyQt 4.11.4 (licensed under the GNU General Public
License) for Python 2.7.9 on linux2.

Type 'L' to view the license.
Type 'yes' to accept the terms of the license.
Type 'no' to decline the terms of the license.

Do you accept the terms of the license? yes
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Search "expect for python" for hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PyQt configure script has an option which automatically confirms acceptance of the licence:

```
python configure.py --confirm-license
```

Since there are no other parts of the PyQt installation process that require user input, that should be all you need. For more details, see [Installing PyQt4](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html#configuring-pyqt4) in the PyQt Docs.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a PyQt problem! ;)

Answer (score 3):

While a particularly difficult script might do some magic to explicitly read from the terminal rather than `stdin`, odds are you could just pipe to the script using bash pipeline syntax:

```
echo yes | python configure.py
```

or if you prefer, the "single command" version using `bash` here string syntax:

```
python configure.py <<<yes
```

Lastly, if you need to provide multiple lines of input, probably the easiest approach is bash's heredoc syntax:

```
# Remove the single quotes if you need to do variable interpolation in the
# heredoc; the delimiter ENDOFINPUT is arbitrary, it just has to be used
# (with or without single quotes) after the `<<` operator, and w/o quotes
# at the end of the input to terminate the heredoc
python configure.py <<'ENDOFINPUT'
yes
anotherresponse
andyetanother
ENDOFINPUT
```

Comment: Instead this solution could works for me, I was looking a solution for PyQt installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide input using pip operator 
(thanks ShadowRanger)
Example:

```
echo "yes"  | command
echo "pass" | ssh user@pass
```

Comment: Wrong pipe operator, piping from command to command is `|`, not `>` (`>` will create a new file named `command` in the first case containing the string `yes\n`).